# Solve for the gradient of $\log \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{m} \exp(a_i^Tx + bi)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, vector-analysis, matrix-calculus

This is a standard problem in convex optimization with well known solution but I cannot seem to follow the procedure given in [Boyd's CVX book](http://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf) pg 643

Suppose I am given $f(x) = \log \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{m} \exp(a_i^Tx + bi)$, $f: R^n \to R$, I need to find the gradient

Then, by the chain rule:

$Df(x) = Dg(h(x))Dh(x)= D(\log \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{m} \exp(a_i^Tx + bi))D( \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{m} \exp(a_i^Tx + bi))$

$Df(x) = \dfrac{1}{\sum\limits_{i = 1}^{m} \exp(a_i^Tx + bi)} [?? \text{what is } D( \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{m} \exp(a_i^Tx + bi))??] $

I would really appreciate if someone can show me how you would get a closed form of the expression $D( \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{m} \exp(a_i^Tx + bi))$.

The final solution is $\nabla f(x) = \dfrac{1}{1^Tz}A^Tz$, where $z_i = \exp(a_i^Tx + b_i)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split it up. Calculate each partial derivative of each term of the sum separately. By the chain rule we have
$$\partial_{x_j}\exp(a_i^Tx+bi)=\exp(a_i^Tx+bi)\partial_{x_j}(a^T_ix+bi)=a_{ij}\exp(a_i^Tx+bi).$$
Hence $D\sum_{i=1}^m\exp(a_i^Tx+bi)=(\sum_{i=1}^ma_{ij}z_i)_{j=1}^n=A^Tz$.

Comment: Thanks for the derivation but I am confused as to why when $\partial_{x_j}$ hits the$ (a_i^Tx + b_i)$ term, $a_{ij}$ pops out. Could you be more explicit about that?

Comment: Are you saying you're having difficulty seeing that $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} a_i^Tx = a_{ij}$?

Comment: Let $a_i = [a_1,...,a_n]^T, x = [x_1, ..., x_n]$, then $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}$ hits $x_j$ for $(a_i^Tx + b_i)$ and pops out $a_j$...but in any case I am clear on derivation of this result just the notation is quite confusing.

Answer (score 8):

I had to peek at the PDF you linked, to see that the notation $a^T_i$ denotes the $i^{th}$ row of the matrix $A$, rather than the transpose of the $i^{th}$ column of the matrix.

You can approach the problem using sequential change-of-variables within differential expressions.  This is useful in matrix calculus, because quite often the intermediate quantities needed to apply the chain-rule are higher order tensors which are difficult to work with in standard matrix-vector notation.

Define the variables 
$$\eqalign{
 y &= Ax + b \cr
 z &= \exp(y) \cr
 s &= 1:z \cr
 f &= \log(s) \cr
}$$
where colon denotes the Frobenius product $($so that $1\!:\!z=1^Tz)$ and the functions are applied element-wise to vector arguments.

Now expand the differential of $f$ in terms of these variables
$$\eqalign{
 df &= d\log(s) = \frac{ds}{s} \cr
   &= \frac{1:dz}{s} \cr
   &= \frac{1:z\circ dy}{s} = \frac{1\circ z:dy}{s} \cr
   &= \frac{z:dy}{s} = \frac{z:A\,dx}{s} \cr
   &= \frac{A^Tz:dx}{s} = \frac{A^Tz}{s}:dx \cr
}$$
where $\circ$ denotes the Hadamard product.  The advantage of using the Frobenius and Hadamard products is that they commute, i.e. $\,A\circ B:C=A: B\circ C,\,$ which can sometimes simplify your results.

Since $df=(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}):dx,\,$ the gradient is 
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} &= \frac{A^Tz}{s} = \frac{A^Tz}{1^Tz} \cr
}$$